# get_row and get_column by reference in Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have a Matrix, and how can I `get_row()` by row reference and `get_column`  by column reference?

One of theseI can't get by reference(I tried via row-major `ordering` and column major `ordering` but it didn't solve this problem because I need both get by reference). How can I redefine(override)  `vector` to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: some code could help to solve this :)

Comment: Ignoring that this is a bad question, you can't have it both ways. Depending on whether you're using column- or row-major, you can either have a row by reference or column by reference.

Comment: Step 1 is to post the code for your matrix.

Comment: You could do it by writing a matrix class that internally had both representation. However, that would be a really inefficient data structure. Maybe you should rather explain what problem you are trying to solve - maybe it will turn out that you don't need both references. To me this sounds like a XY problem - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: you can't get a raw pointer to both single row and single column, since one of them will not be laid out contiguously, but you can use some intermediate classes that will account for that, e.g. your `get_column` can return some object that will behave as a reference to column

Comment: I solve this problem ))

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't ignore all the people who ask you to post the code of your class.

That said, what you could do is to define something that works comparably to an iterator wrt a row or a column. Not what you actually asked for, but since the memory can't be consecutive for both rows and columns, you need a custom type anyway.

Here is an example layout, of course with a lot of things omitted. I haven't put that much thought into it, might easily be that there is a way better pattern. I'm creating the matrix class as a class over double, most likely you'd use a template instead.

```
class Matrix{

    class RowIterator;

    friend class RowIterator;

    private:
        vector<vector<double> > data;

    public:

        RowIterator row_iterator(const unsigned int row);

    }

class Matrix::RowIterator{

    private:
        Matrix* parent;
        unsigned int row;
        unsigned int col;

    public:

        double& operator * ();
        RowIterator& operator++()
        bool equals(const unsigned int column) const;
}
```

with

```
double& Matrix::RowIterator::operator * (){
    return parent->data[row][col];
}
Matrix::RowIterator& Matrix::RowIterator::operator++(){
    col++;
    return *this;
}
bool equals(const unsigned int column) const{
    return column == col;
}
```

and ColumnIterator likewise (or both as one class that stores and additional member of what it is), also define

```
inline bool operator==(const Matrix::RowIterator& lhs, const unsigned int rhs){
    return lhs.equals(rhs)
}
```

and likewise the other way around and the !=-operator

to be able to do code like

```
for(Matrix::RowIterator it = matrix.row_iterator(desired_row); it != matrix.columns(); it++)
```

(or alternatively go with something that leads to

```
for(Matrix::RowIterator it = matrix.row_iterator(desired_row); it.at_valid_position(); it++)
```

)

Again, there might be a way better pattern, not sure about that. Would be happy about an edit of somebody who knows this better than me.

Also, of course this could simply be done by feeding something with the matrix and the desired row instead and having it simply iterate over the column itself - therefore I wasn't sure about posting this answer. Depends on what you want to do and what the organic logic is to be - would recommend that in addition to the code of your matrix, you also post a clear description of what you wanted to do with those references.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Aziuth

Comment: @Lilit (Psst: if it actually solved your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - of course, only if it did. Not sure about that though, still don't know your context. In that case, elaborate your question and I'll be glad to help.)

Comment: Actually, I would like to see other solutions also

Comment: @Lilia Then I can only emphasize that it is imperative for others to know your context. What exactly do you want to do with the vectors that are extracted? Iterate through them? Write them? Stream them?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, to be more vector-like:

```
enum MatrixSubVectorType{ row_vector, column_vector };

class MatrixSubVector{

private:

    MatrixSubVectorType type;
    unsigned int fixed_coordinate;
    Matrix* parent;

public:

    double& operator[] (unsigned int i);
    const double& operator [] (unsigned int i);

    unsigned int size() const;
}

double& MatrixSubVector::operator[] (unsigned int i) {

    if(type == row_vector){
        return (*parent)(fixed_coordinate, i);
    }
    return (*parent)(i, fixed_coordinate);
}

unsigned int MatrixSubVector::size() const {

    if(type == row_vector){
        return parent->columns();
    }
    return parent->rows()
}
```

With a lot of things omitted of course, like constructors, just to show the pattern. Like with the other pattern, I'd make this as an inner class of Matrix, with Matrix as a friend, the constructor being private and objects of that class only to be created by a method of Matrix.

Comment: As I mention earlier I want to get column and row by reference both

Comment: Something like this:  
column& get_column(size_type column_index)
    {
        return m_columns[column_index];
    }
    
    row& get_row(size_type row_index)
    {
        return m_data[row_index];
    }

Comment: @Lilia The important question is what you want to do with it. Again, and please answer this time: " What exactly do you want to do with the vectors that are extracted? Iterate through them? Write them? Stream them?" - this is the important thing here. Everything else is XY-problem. Not "I want this" but "In order to...". Together with what is important - if memory is unimportant, for example, you could simply go with a matrix class that also stores additional vector that contain pointers at the data. You'd need something like that for the signature you used, by the nature of references.